# Horizontal Inline List Padding

Tags: html, css, html-lists, padding

I've got a horizontal html inline list, which is used for navigation, and I want to remove the padding between the list items. This is because there are images inside each box which need to be touching.

I've tried setting margins/padding to 0 for both the nav container, and the list itself, but it won't work. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="navwrapper">
            <ul id="navlist">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/nav/about.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/nav/gigs.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/nav/music.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/nav/facebook.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#navwrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 26px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#navwrapper ul {
text-align: right;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#navlist {
height: 26px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#navlist li {
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #000000;
}
```

Thanks!

Sparkles*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is actually because the new lines you have between the `<li>`'s are being formatted as spaces. Simply put all of those tags in your code on the same line, like so:

`<li></li><li></li>`

..rather than..

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can float the list as required. Here's an example update to the CSS that should work, assuming there's no other issues with the box model:

```
#navwrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  clear: right; /* clear the children that are floated right */
}

ul#navlist {
  float: right; /* float all of this to the right */
  list-style: none;
  height: 26px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  clear: left; /* clear the children that are floated left */
}

ul#navlist li {
  float: left; /* float the box left, so we can set margin/padding */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: hey Kush, cheers for the help! I just removed the periods, seemed to work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

`float` the `li`'s:

http://jsfiddle.net/durilai/g7KRe/

Answer (score 1):

All the modern browsers can help you find this kind of problem via 'inspect element' features.  (You'll want the FireBug add-in if you're using Firefox).

The browser will show you what styles are applied to each element, and where the padding comes from.

Getting used to inspecting elements in the browser will be much more useful than getting a lucky guess here from someone about this particular problem.